# Mass 301 Moved Permanently redirect

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am having trouble finding the best way to redirect 25+ pages to their new URLs. I have updated a weebly site to a PHP one so all the .html links are now .php and some files are renamed completely (updating since the old site wasn't mobile responsive).

I have try some `.htaccess` things to change `.html`  extensions to `.php` ones but it doesn't seem to work on my shared host.

Is there a `php 301 redirect` I can use and include on the `404 page`? or will the hurt SEO? Having a 404 to 301 to new page? Is there another way? Other than creating HTML page with the old names and adding meta refresh? or using `.htaccess`?

I have looked at a lot of over stacks but their not SEO focus or don't match my pro, I really want to keep SEO in mind.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.sitename.co.nz/404_error.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .html$
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /$1.php [R=301,L]

#http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess

Redirect 301 /oldfilea.htm /newfilea.htm
Redirect 301 /oldfileb.htm /newfileb.htm
Redirect 301 /oldfilec.htm /newfilec.htm
Redirect 301 /oldfilee.htm /newfilee.htm
Redirect 301 /oldfiled.htm /newfiled.htm
```

Comment: Firstly, please show us what you've tried with `.htaccess`. Also, a breakdown of what needs to be redirected would help.

Comment: To get better help post your current .htaccess in question.

Comment: @anubhava @Mike Rockett  I've added some of the things i've tried. note that I have tried each of these on their own and only `ErrorDocument 404 http://www.sitename.co.nz/404_error.php` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of important changes needed:

1. Don't mix `mod_alias` rules with `mod_rewrite` rules.
2. Keep redirect rules before internal rewrite ones.

Try this in root .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.sitename.co.nz/404_error.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^oldfilea\.htm$ /newfilea.htm [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^oldfileb\.htm$ /newfileb.htm [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^oldfilec\.htm$ /newfilec.htm [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^oldfilee\.htm$ /newfilee.htm [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^oldfiled\.htm$ /newfiled.htm [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ /$1.php [R=301,L,NC]
```

Test this after clearing your browser cache.